# How to count rows of interest from a field in an attribute table using arcpy.da.Cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

How to count the number of records from a field 'COVER' that is neither 'woods' and neither 'orchards'?

```
fileName = 'C:/gispy/data/ch17/parkCopy3.shp'
fields = ['COVER', 'FID']

count = 0 .

try:

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fileName, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != 'woods' or row[0] != 'orchards':
            count = row[0].count
            cursor.updateRow(row)

    del cursor
print 'Number of records with other cover types:{0}'.format(count)
```

except:

Comment: What's the error you faced with in python ? The code in the question is not complete. Also has syntax error "." after count = 0

Comment: I don't face any error, i just don't know how to handle the count for the other records that are not woods and orchards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/gispy/data/ch17"
fileName = 'parkCopy3.shp'
fields = ['COVER', 'FID']
myList = ['woods', 'orchards']
count = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fileName, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in myList:
            count += 1

print 'Number of records with other cover types:{0}'.format(count)
```

1. Don't forget to **import arcpy** at the beginning of the code.
2. Use List to iterate the values (Cover and orchards)
3. If you want just search and print the result, Use **SearchCursor**. You don't   need to use **UpdateCursor**.
4. I removed try- except because your code was not complete. Maybe you don't need to use try-except in your code.

Comment: and here's the obligatory plug for list comprehension :) `count = len([i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fileName,fields) if not i[0] in myList])`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cursor to do that, `GetCount()` returns what you want. 
If you're using a database instead of a shapefile, this approach will probably be faster too.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/gispy/data/ch17/parkCopy3.shp", "selection", "COVER not in ('woods', 'orchards')")
print arcpy.GetCount_management("selection").getOutput(0)
```

For Desktop: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm

For Pro: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm

Comment: The question says nothing about either Pro *or* Desktop, so I assume either is correct. I'll include a link to the Desktop documentation too, although it's identical to Pro.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to select the rows you want to count and then run the summary statistics tool. These could be called from a python script or knocked together using model builder in half the time.